# Regex to validate 3 repeating characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to validate password which should not allow 3 repeating characters regardless of their position in the string.

For example :

121121 - Not Accepted, since 1 appears more than 3 times.

121212 - accepted, since 1 and 2 appears only 3 times

I tried this

```
([0-9])\1{2,}
```

But its validating only consecutive repeated digits.

Comment: I don't think you can do this (in a reasonable way) with regex. Not everything can be handled with regex. Your regex would have to remember "state" (i.e., the count) about every single possible character, which it's not designed to do.

Comment: [`^(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1.*\1).*`](https://regex101.com/r/UJMCS7/1) will do it, but it is very inefficient.

Comment: `(.)(?:.*?\1){3}` will do it, a bit more efficiently that Wiktors, because it uses reluctant quantifiers between repeating character instead of greedy quantifiers, but it is still not very efficient. A better solution would be a count-by-character, i.e. not a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much for your regex. Could you please explain your regex? It worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The regex solution for this is very inefficient**. Please consider treating this answer from pure academic interest.

The pattern that fails strings having 4 or more occurrences of the same char is

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1.*\1).*
```

The last `.*` may be replaced with a more restrictive pattern if you need to precise this pattern.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UJMCS7/1).

The main part here is the `(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1.*\1)` negative lookahead. It matches
 any 0+ chars (if `Pattern.DOTALL` is used, any char including newlines), as many as possible, then it matches and *captures* (with `(.)`) any char into Group 1, and then matches any 0+ chars followed with the same char 3 times. If the pattern is found (matched), the whole string match fails.

**Why is it inefficient?** The pattern relies heavily on backtracking. `.*` grabs all chars to the end of the string, then the engine backtracks, trying to accommodate some text for the subsequent subpatterns. You may see the [backtracking steps here](https://regex101.com/r/fTR7he/1/debugger). The more `.*` there is, the more resource-consuming the pattern is.

**Why is lazy variant not any better?** The `^(?!.*?(.).*?\1.*?\1.*?\1).*` looks to be faster with some strings, and it will be faster if the repeating chars appear close to each other and the start of the string. If they are at the end of the string, the efficiency will degrade. So, if the previous regex matches `121212` in 77 steps, the current one will also take the same amount of steps. However, if you test it against `1212124444`, you will see that the lazy variant [will fail after 139 steps](https://regex101.com/r/fTR7he/2), while the greedy variant will [fail after 58 steps](https://regex101.com/r/fTR7he/3). And vice versa, `4444121212` will cause the lazy regex fail quicker, [14 steps](https://regex101.com/r/fTR7he/5) vs. [211 steps with the greedy variant](https://regex101.com/r/fTR7he/4).

In Java, you may use it

```
s.matches("(?!.*(.).*\\1.*\\1.*\\1)")
```

or

```
s.matches("(?!.*?(.).*?\\1.*?\\1.*?\\1)")
```

Use [Jacob's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395977/3832970) in production.

Comment: Will "(.)\1\1" avoid those backtracing problems? I think it only takes all character and compares it with the chars behind it.

Comment: @ChenLin That will change the meaning, and thus, matches. `(.)\1\1` matches *consecutive identical chars other than line break chars, it does not allow any text in between them.

Answer (score 6):

I don't recommend using regular expressions for something like this, as it would be easier to just collect the password into a `Map` where a count of each character is maintained.  Then, you can just check if there exists any character which has a count of more than `3`:

```
password.chars()
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(i -> i > 3);
```

This returns `true` if there exists some character in `password` that appears more than `3` times, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Easier than [a short regex and simple single method call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396466/256196)? Not in IMHO.

Comment: Great answer but I don't understand why "(.)\1\1" will be less efficient.

Comment: @ChenLin Thanks! The pattern that you specified is for three repeating **sequential** characters, whereas the OP specifies that they don't need to be sequential.

Comment: @JacobG. My mistake...But will this one cause efficiency problem anyway?

Comment: @ChenLin I'm not sure if you're referring to my solution, or your proposed regular expression pattern. My solution only has to iterate over the `String` once to count the frequency of each character, and then iterate over the frequencies to determine if any occurred more than three times. If the OP was only concerned with repeating sequential characters, then your solution would be fine efficiency-wise.

Comment: @JacobG. I am just trying to find the best way to do this in production. Being new to regex, I am worried about efficiency. Thank you so much for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex with a negative look ahead with back reference:

```
boolean ok = str.matches("((.)(?!(.*\\2){3}))+");
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/gkeoSyuIUs).

In English, this regex says "every character must not appear 3 more times after itself".

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a map instead,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(validate("121121"));
    System.out.println(validate("121212"));
}

static boolean validate(String s)
{
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray())
    {
        if (map.containsKey(c))
        {
            map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(c , 1);
        }
    }

    for (Integer count : map.values())
    {
        if (count > 3)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```